# Xpages FTSearch - would "verry" match "very" in fuzzy searches

Tags: xpages, fuzzy-search

I want to check how the fuzzy search works (esp in Lotus Notes databases). What kind of variants can I expect to match with fuzzy search?

Comment: Look here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21088269

Comment: Thanks Knut.. so "verry" should return "very" as it is a mis-spelled but it does not. :-(

Comment: Maybe that's why: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verry :-) But it falls into category "too short" I guess: "Fuzzy Search is not designed to work on small words".

Comment: seems like it.. thanks anyway!!